# My app uses a number of Input Text boxes to make certain calculations and it works fine, unless I backspace to change the number

Tags: flutter, dart

My app uses a number of Input Text boxes to make certain calculations and it works fine, unless I backspace to change the number and then Visual Studio Code opens up a screen showing the file "errors_patch.dart". I'm not sure why this happens, but strangely only happens if I haven't filled in all the Input Text boxes. What can I try next?

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const appTitle = 'Diabetic insulin dosage';
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: appTitle,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text(appTitle),
          backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
          foregroundColor: Colors.black,
        ),
        body: const AddTwoNumbers(),
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class AddTwoNumbers extends StatefulWidget {
  const AddTwoNumbers({super.key});

  @override
  // ignore: library_private_types_in_public_api
  _AddTwoNumbersState createState() => _AddTwoNumbersState();
}

class _AddTwoNumbersState extends State<AddTwoNumbers> {
  Color _fillColor = Colors.white;

  TextEditingController numR1C1controller =
      TextEditingController(); //Changed name of the texteditingcontroller as Row as R and Column as C
  TextEditingController numR1C2controller = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController numR1C3controller = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController numR2C1controller = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController numR2C2controller = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController numR2C3controller = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController numR3C1controller = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController numR3C2controller = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController numR3C3controller = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController numR4C1controller = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController numR4C2controller = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController numR4C3controller = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController numR5C1controller = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController numR5C2controller = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController numR5C3controller = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController numR6C1controller = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController numR6C2controller = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController numR6C3controller = TextEditingController();

  String result = "0";
  String result2 = "0";
  String result3 = "0";
  String result4 = "0";
  String result5 = "0";
  String result6 = "0";

  // MAKE LIST OF MAP TO KEEP TRACK OF EACH BUTTONS
  List<Map> buttons = [
    {"name": "BreakFast", "active": false, "value": 1.0},
    {"name": "Lunch", "active": false, "value": 0.55},
    {"name": "Tea", "active": false, "value": 0.55},
  ];

  // YOU CAN SET VARIABLE TO CURRENT MEAL NAME AND CAN CHECK WHETHER IT'S (breakFast) OR NOT
  String? currentMealType;

  // TOGGLE BUTTON FUNCTION
  toggleButtons(Map obj) {
    for (var i in buttons) {
      if (i['name'] == obj['name']) {
        i['active'] = !i['active'];
        numR2C2controller.text = obj['value'].toString();
        _calculateR2();
      } else {
        i['active'] = false;
      }
    }

    setState(() {});
  }

  _calculateR1() {
    if (numR1C1controller.text.isNotEmpty &&
        numR1C2controller.text.isNotEmpty) {
      double sum = double.parse(numR1C1controller.text) -
          double.parse(numR1C2controller.text);
      numR4C2controller.text = numR1C2controller.text;
      numR2C1controller.text = numR1C1controller.text; // <-- add this
      WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
        _calculateR3();
        _calculateR2();
      });
      result = sum.toStringAsFixed(1);
    }

    if (numR1C2controller.text.isNotEmpty) {
      setState(() {
        _fillColor = double.parse(numR1C2controller.text) < 5
            ? Colors.red
            : double.parse(numR1C2controller.text) > 9.1
                ? Colors.orange
                : Colors.green;
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        _fillColor = Colors.white;
      });
    }
  }

  _calculateR2() {
    if (numR2C1controller.text.isNotEmpty &&
        numR2C2controller.text.isNotEmpty) {
      setState(() {
        double sum = double.parse(numR2C2controller.text) *
            double.parse(numR2C1controller.text);
        numR2C3controller.text = sum.toStringAsFixed(1);
        numR3C1controller.text = numR2C3controller.text;
        WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
          _calculateR3();
        });
        result2 = sum.toStringAsFixed(1);
      });
    }
  }

  _calculateR3() {
    if (numR3C1controller.text.isNotEmpty &&
        numR3C2controller.text.isNotEmpty) {
      setState(() {
        double sum = double.parse(numR3C1controller.text) /
            double.parse(numR3C2controller.text);
        numR3C3controller.text = sum.toStringAsFixed(1);
        numR6C1controller.text = numR3C3controller.text;
        WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
          _calculateR3();
          _calculateR4();
          _calculateR6();
        });
        result3 = sum.toStringAsFixed(1);
      });
    }
  }

  _calculateR4() {
    if (numR4C1controller.text.isNotEmpty &&
        numR4C2controller.text.isNotEmpty) {
      setState(() {
        double sum = double.parse(numR4C1controller.text) -
            double.parse(numR4C2controller.text);
        numR4C3controller.text = sum.toStringAsFixed(1);
        numR5C1controller.text = numR4C3controller.text;
        WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
          _calculateR5();
        });
        result4 = sum.toStringAsFixed(1);
      });
    }
  }

  _calculateR5() {
    if (numR5C1controller.text.isNotEmpty &&
        numR5C2controller.text.isNotEmpty) {
      setState(() {
        double sum = double.parse(numR5C1controller.text) /
            double.parse(numR5C2controller.text);
        numR5C3controller.text = sum.toStringAsFixed(1);
        numR6C2controller.text = numR5C3controller.text;
        result5 = sum.toStringAsFixed(1);
      });
    }
  }

  _calculateR6() {
    if (numR6C1controller.text.isNotEmpty &&
        numR6C2controller.text.isNotEmpty) {
      setState(() {
        double sum = double.parse(numR6C1controller.text) -
            double.parse(numR6C2controller.text);
        numR6C3controller.text = sum.toStringAsFixed(1);
        result6 = sum.toStringAsFixed(1);
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          const Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
            child: Text('Please pick a meal'),
          ),

          // HERE IS THE VIEW FOR BUTTONS
          //******************************

          Row(
            children: buttons
                .map(
                  (btn) => Expanded(
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () => toggleButtons(btn),
                      child: Container(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10, right: 10),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: btn['active'] ? Colors.blue : Colors.white,
                            border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey[300]!)),
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            Text(btn['name'],
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: btn['active']
                                        ? Colors.white
                                        : Colors.black)),
                            Text(btn['value'].toString(),
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: btn['active']
                                        ? Colors.white
                                        : Colors.black))
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
                .toList(),
          ),
          const Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
            child: Text('Input Data'),
          ),

          //******************************

          Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                child: TextField(
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0),
                  controller: numR1C1controller,
                  onChanged: (value) => _calculateR1(),
                  keyboardType:
                      const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
                  inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                    FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                        RegExp(r'^(\d+)?\.?\d{0,1}'))
                  ],
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                      border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
                      labelText: 'Carbs in Meal',
                      isDense: true,
                      hintText: 'Enter 1st Number',
                      fillColor: _fillColor,
                      filled: false),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                width: 8,
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: TextField(
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0),
                  onChanged: (value) => _calculateR1(),
                  keyboardType:
                      const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
                  controller: numR1C2controller,
                  inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                    FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                        RegExp(r'^(\d+)?\.?\d{0,1}'))
                  ],
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                      border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
                      filled: true,
                      labelText: 'Current B/G Level',
                      isDense: true,
                      hintText: 'Enter 2nd Number',
                      fillColor: _fillColor),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                width: 8,
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: TextField(
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0),
                  onChanged: (value) => _calculateR1(),
                  keyboardType:
                      const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
                  controller: numR1C3controller,
                  inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                    FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                        RegExp(r'^(\d+)?\.?\d{0,2}'))
                  ],
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    labelText: 'Excercise Factor',
                    isDense: true,
                    hintText: '',
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                width: 8,
              ),
            ],
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 8,
          ),
          const Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
            child: Text('Calculations'),
          ),
          Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: TextField(
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, height: 1.0),
                  onChanged: (value) => _calculateR2(),
                  keyboardType:
                      const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
                  controller: numR2C1controller,
                  inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                    FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                        RegExp(r'^(\d+)?\.?\d{0,2}'))
                  ],
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(3),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    labelText: 'T Carbs in meal',
                    hintText: 'Enter 3rd Number',
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                width: 8,
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: TextField(
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                  onChanged: (value) => _calculateR2(),
                  keyboardType:
                      const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
                  controller: numR2C2controller,
                  inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                    FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                        RegExp(r'^(\d+)?\.?\d{0,2}'))
                  ],
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(3),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    labelText: 'T Meal Ratio',
                    hintText: 'Enter 4th Number',
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                width: 8,
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: TextField(
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                  onChanged: (value) => _calculateR3(),
                  keyboardType:
                      const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
                  controller: numR2C3controller,
                  inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                    FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                        RegExp(r'^(\d+)?\.?\d{0,2}'))
                  ],
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(3),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    labelText: 'Result 2',
                    hintText: '',
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                width: 8,
              ),
            ],
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 8,
          ),
          Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: TextField(
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                  onChanged: (value) => _calculateR3(),
                  keyboardType:
                      const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
                  controller: numR3C1controller,
                  inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                    FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                        RegExp(r'^(\d+)?\.?\d{0,2}'))
                  ],
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(3),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    labelText: 'T Result 2',
                    hintText: 'Enter Fifth Number',
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                width: 8,
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: TextField(
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                  onChanged: (value) => _calculateR3(),
                  keyboardType:
                      const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
                  controller: numR3C2controller,
                  inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                    FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                        RegExp(r'^(\d+)?\.?\d{0,2}'))
                  ],
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(3),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    labelText: 'Correction Factor',
                    hintText: 'Enter Sixth Number',
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                width: 8,
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: TextField(
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                  onChanged: (value) => _calculateR3(),
                  keyboardType:
                      const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
                  controller: numR3C3controller,
                  inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                    FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                        RegExp(r'^(\d+)?\.?\d{0,2}'))
                  ],
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(3),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    labelText: 'Result 3',
                    hintText: '',
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                width: 8,
              ),
            ],
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 8,
          ),
          Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: TextField(
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                  onChanged: (value) => _calculateR4(),
                  keyboardType:
                      const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
                  controller: numR4C1controller,
                  inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                    FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                        RegExp(r'^(\d+)?\.?\d{0,2}'))
                  ],
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(3),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    labelText: 'T Target Level',
                    hintText: 'Enter Seventh Number',
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                width: 8,
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: TextField(
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                  onChanged: (value) => _calculateR4(),
                  keyboardType:
                      const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
                  controller: numR4C2controller,
                  inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                    FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                        RegExp(r'^(\d+)?\.?\d{0,2}'))
                  ],
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(3),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    labelText: 'T Current B/G Level',
                    // isDense: true,
                    hintText: 'Enter Eighth Number',
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                width: 8,
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: TextField(
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                  onChanged: (value) => _calculateR4(),
                  keyboardType:
                      const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
                  controller: numR4C3controller,
                  inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                    FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                        RegExp(r'^(\d+)?\.?\d{0,2}'))
                  ],
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(3),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    labelText: 'Result 4',
                    // isDense: true,
                    hintText: '',
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                width: 8,
              ),
            ],
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 8,
          ),
          Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: TextField(
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                  onChanged: (value) => _calculateR5(),
                  keyboardType:
                      const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
                  controller: numR5C1controller,
                  inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                    FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                        RegExp(r'^(\d+)?\.?\d{0,2}'))
                  ],
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(3),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    labelText: 'T Result Difference',
                    hintText: 'Enter 9th Number',
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                width: 8,
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: TextField(
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                  onChanged: (value) => _calculateR5(),
                  keyboardType:
                      const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
                  controller: numR5C2controller,
                  inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                    FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                        RegExp(r'^(\d+)?\.?\d{0,2}'))
                  ],
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(3),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    labelText: 'Correction Factor',
                    hintText: 'Enter 10th Number',
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                width: 8,
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: TextField(
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                  onChanged: (value) => _calculateR5(),
                  keyboardType:
                      const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
                  controller: numR5C3controller,
                  inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                    FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                        RegExp(r'^(\d+)?\.?\d{0,2}'))
                  ],
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(3),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    labelText: 'Result 5',
                    hintText: '',
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                width: 8,
              ),
            ],
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 8,
          ),
          Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: TextField(
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                  onChanged: (value) => _calculateR6(),
                  keyboardType:
                      const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
                  controller: numR6C1controller,
                  inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                    FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                        RegExp(r'^(\d+)?\.?\d{0,2}'))
                  ],
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(3),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    labelText: 'T Result Actual Units',
                    hintText: 'Enter 11th Number',
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                width: 8,
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: TextField(
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                  onChanged: (value) => _calculateR6(),
                  keyboardType:
                      const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
                  controller: numR6C2controller,
                  inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                    FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                        RegExp(r'^(\d+)?\.?\d{0,2}'))
                  ],
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(3),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    labelText: 'Result Difference',
                    // isDense: true,
                    hintText: 'Enter 12th Number',
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                width: 8,
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: TextField(
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                  onChanged: (value) => _calculateR6(),
                  keyboardType:
                      const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
                  controller: numR6C3controller,
                  inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                    FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                        RegExp(r'^(\d+)?\.?\d{0,2}'))
                  ],
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(3),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    labelText: 'Result 6',
                    // isDense: true,
                    hintText: '',
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                width: 8,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely facing this issue because of TextEditingController, and you are not disposing the controller when the widget is removed from widget tree
so in order to fix the issue you can try this code:

```
class _AddTwoNumbersState extends State<AddTwoNumbers> {
  // TextEditingController code goes here

  // Add a dispose() method to dispose of the controllers
  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Call dispose() on each of the controllers
    numR1C1controller.dispose();
    numR1C2controller.dispose();
    numR1C3controller.dispose();
    numR2C1controller.dispose();
    numR2C2controller.dispose();
    numR2C3controller.dispose();
    numR3C1controller.dispose();
    numR3C2controller.dispose();
    numR3C3controller.dispose();
    numR4C1controller.dispose();
    numR4C2controller.dispose();
    numR4C3controller.dispose();
    numR5C1controller.dispose();
    numR5C2controller.dispose();
    numR5C3controller.dispose();
    numR6C1controller.dispose();
    numR6C2controller.dispose();
    numR6C3controller.dispose();

    // Call super.dispose() to ensure the state is properly disposed
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @sadji for your help.  I'm new to coding so struggling to know exactly where to put your suggested code, as I have tried it in 3 places so far but all just cause lots of problems?  I assume I just need the "@override" line, the "void dispose() {" line and the 18 lines mentioning all the controller numbers? but which line would that be placed on please?